# SMSManager not working in Android having no error

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm working on Android application in which I'm using `SMSManager`, but the problem is that I'm not able to send the SMS directly. It is also not showing any error. My code is given below:

```
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(newData,null,"Join Company",null, null); 
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(newData, null,message, null, null);
```

I have used `try` and `catch` to check for any error, but it is not showing any error as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very clear also,but you can try to get the permission of send sms dynamically
 rather than `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`
I have meet the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You used only 1 part of the SMSManager.

```
   SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);


Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

**Android Manifest**
 Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don't want to show my native application for sending sms. It is not working here.. It just open my native sms application and showing "default content".